# How to create splash screen when Excel start?

Tags: excel, splash-screen

I am new to excel programming and I want to create a popup screen when my excel file is opened so can anyone tell me how to create a splash screen when excel start?

Comment: i mean i like a screen that gives info related to my project and other stuff ... like every application does when it start it gives the brief info about it

Comment: I've recommended it be migrated to SO where it belongs. People there will be able to help you better.

Comment: but I thought it might be good to ask here as it is more relevant for the people using Excel, but its ok I am looking for the answer only despite of its place ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Build a custom form that consists entirely of the desired splash image. Then call that form for a set period of time upon the load of your spreadsheet/app.

UPDATE Now with code (or at least links):

Like I said above, this question is dealt with extensively on forums across the inter-verse.

[DailyDose seems to have the simplest and most straightforward](http://www.dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2004/09/27/splash-screen/) implementation of the splash screen, making a few important points about running the form as modal to allow your app code to keep running behind the splash.

The code is very simple:

```
    Sub StartProgram()
        Dim dtDelay As Date

        dtDelay = Now
        ufSplash.Show

        ‘Do initialization stuff
         If Now < (dtDelay + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)) Then
             Application.Wait dtDelay + TimeSerial(0, 0, 5)
         End If

         Unload ufSplash

    End Sub
```

[VBA Express has a macro that'll run a slow fade on the form](http://www.vbaexpress.com/kb/getarticle.php?kb_id=166) and then close it when it gets completely invisible.